# ReactJS/JavaScript find array in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a string `value` and an object `obj`, want to convert `value` to `array` then find it in `obj` by value, and get `name` but it return `undefined`, what I have missed?

```js
let value = '3,4';
let obj = {
  "DistrictData": [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": 'blah'
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": 'oops'
  }]
}

let res = value.split(',').map((v, i) => obj.DistrictData.find(o => o.id === v))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: `===` compares both the type and the value, and you're comparing a `string` and a `number` which means `o.id === v` will never be `true`, try using just `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find with a number value, because split returns an array of strings. Then map the name as well.

```js
let value = '3,4',
    obj = { DistrictData: [{ id: 3, name: 'blah' }, { id: 4, name: 'oops' }] },
    res = value
        .split(',')
        .map((v, i) => obj.DistrictData.find(o => o.id === +v))
        .map(o => o.name);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The split array contains string value and within find you are comparing string with number so either convert string to number or use `==` to ignore checking type. And finally get the `name` property from the object.

```js
let value = '3,4';
let obj = {
  "DistrictData": [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": 'blah'
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": 'oops'
  }]
}

let res = value.split(',').map((v, i) => (bj.DistrictData.find(o => o.id == v).name)
console.log(res)
```

Refer : [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 1):

you can normalize array

to like

```
  let obj = { "DistrictData": {"3":{ "id": 3,"name": 'blah'}, "4":{"id": 4,"name": 'oops'}}
```

then you can filter on name

[normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)